# Why is the past also represented as a light cone in the opposite direction? (layman)

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime

I recently heard about light cones as mentioned in Stephen Hawking's A Brief History of Time. I understand light can be seen as a cone when a flash of light is spread from an `event` (point in spacetime) and confined to a 2D plane and then extended along a perpendicular axis representing time. Why is it that there is also a "mirror image" of this cone behind this `event`? What is the point of the `past` here if the light did not yet exist?

[image: Light cone]

A snippet from [Wikipedia: Light cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone#Details) mentioning the past light cone:

> The past light cone behaves like the future light cone in reverse, a
>   circle which contracts in radius at the speed of light until it
>   converges to a point at the exact position and time of the event E.

Comment: I'm adding this to one of your old questions to contact you. Your name implies that you're perhaps interested in creating things. We have a site on the network dedicated to creating fictional worlds called [worldbuilding.se] if you're interested.

Comment: Thank you, Jimmy. I'll check it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The future light cone of an event $A$ contains all other events for which all observers agree that $A$ happened first.

The past light cone contains all other events for which all observers agree that $A$ happened afterwards.

For events outside of either light cone, observers in different reference frames can disagree about whether $A$ happened afterwards or beforehand.  This is important if you are interested in whether two events are causally connected.  We have a theoretical prejudice which suggests you cannot "cause" something which already happened in the past.  If two events $A$ and $B$ are outside of each others' light cones, so that we cannot say which came first, then this prejudice means that neither can have been a cause of the other.

We say that such not-well-ordered events are "spacelike-separated," and that the spacetime around an event is divided into its past, its future, and "elsewhere."

Comment: Thank you. I can now see how the past light cone includes all events that can theoretically reach the current event  and have some effect on it. Thus, I see how an observer at the event  can only observe those events that are in the past light cone. The future light cone contains all events  that may be affected by  itself.  can only be influenced by events in its past light cone and influence events in its future light cone.